# Routing traffic between VNets through VPN Gateway

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, vnet, azure-vpn

I have the following S2S VPN configuration.

[image]

VNet peering configuration details are below:

Vnet A (with VPN Gateway)

[image]

Vnet B

[image]

Both VNets are configured to forward traffic and either use virtual network gateway (Vnet A) or use remote virtual network gateway (in Vnet A) for Vnet B.

Traffic from VM A is flowing through the tunnel easily and I'm able to reach VM C and VM D.

Effective routes for VM A are below:

[image]

However, when trying to establish a connection from VM B to the on-premises hosts (VMs C/D), I got timeouts.

Effective routes for VM B are below:

[image]

I suppose, the problem is in routing thus I created a route table and associated with VM B's Vnet/subnet.

However, I'm quite confused which kind of routing should I choose here:

[image]

in order to be able to ping (connect) from VM B to on-prem VMs C/D.

Answer (score 0):

If the "use gateway" and "use remote gateway" options settings are enabled in Vnet peering(s) and the subnet the packets originating from is configured at the remote party side of the tunnel, then UDR is not needed.

The prerequisites are:

1. Configured address spaces/subnets to send/receive traffic from/to both ends of the tunnel
2. Configured peering between Vnets (if the traffic is originating not from the VPN gateway network)
3. Configured usage of gateways (or remote gateways) in Vnet peering settings

I.e. in my case, the packet sent over the tunnel will be accepted on the remote side of the tunnel if:

a) the Vnet B is added as a routable in the VPN termination endpoint/appliance
b) Source IP address header of the packet has the correct value (from the Vnet B address space)